# How to check which category parent has term meta

Tags: wordpress, multiple-inheritance, categories, taxonomy

I'm trying to achieve the following in Wordpress:

My categories have an extra wysiwyg field set up as term meta. I'm displaying it in my category.php template file. 
But if it's empty, the category should check it's direct parent, and if it finds the field not empty there, then it should inherit that. In case the direct parent has it empty, go to higher level, check and display if found. I need to go 5 levels deep, not more. If all the fields in the whole inheritance tree are empty, then of course don't show anything.

Here is my code so far, so you get an idea.

```
$category = get_the_category();
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $category[0]->term_id, 'category' );
        $direct_parent_id = $ancestors[0];
        $topmost_parent_id = $ancestors[1];
        $level = asb_get_cat_level( $cat );

    if(function_exists('get_tax_meta')) { 
        /* First get Section partner fields */
        $cat_part = get_term_meta(get_queried_object_id(),'cat_part_wysiwyg', true);
        $cat_part_parent = get_term_meta($direct_parent_id,'cat_part_wysiwyg', true);
        $cat_part_grandparent = get_term_meta($topmost_parent_id,'cat_part_wysiwyg', true);

            /* Construct output for Section partners */
            $cat_partner = '<div class="category-partners">' . $cat_part . '</div>';
            $cat_partner_parent = '<div class="category-partners"> ' . $cat_part_parent . '</div>';
            $cat_partner_grandparent = '<div class="category-partners">' . $cat_part_grandparent . '</div>';

            /* Start showing Section partners */
                if( !empty($cat_part_grandparent) ) {
                    print_r($cat_partner_grandparent);
                } elseif( !empty($cat_part_parent) ) {
                    print_r($cat_partner_parent); 
                } elseif ( !empty($cat_part) ) {
                    print_r($cat_partner); 
                } else {
                    /* Die */
                }
        }
```

plus my functions.php has this code:

```
function asb_get_cat_level($id, $type = 'category') {
    return count( get_ancestors($id, $type) );
}
```

(I was using this function inside the conditionals like ($level == 1) etc.)

So far only the topmost category shows up it's Section partners, but it's children don't inherit them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up using this code

```
    // Section Partners 
    function section_partners() {   
        $cat_id = get_query_var('cat');
        $ancestors = get_ancestors( $cat_id, 'category' );

            $parent_one = $ancestors[0];
            $parent_null = $ancestors[1];
            $parent_two = $ancestors[2];                
        // $level = asb_get_cat_level( $cat );

    if(function_exists('get_tax_meta')) { 
        /* First get Section partner fields */
        $cat_part = get_term_meta(get_queried_object_id(),'cat_part_wysiwyg', true);
        $cat_part_parent = get_term_meta($parent_one, 'cat_part_wysiwyg', true);
        $cat_part_grandparent = get_term_meta($parent_null,'cat_part_wysiwyg', true);
        $cat_part_grandgrandparent = get_term_meta($parent_two,'cat_part_wysiwyg', true);


            /* Construct output for Section partners */
            $cat_partner = '<div class="category-partners"><div>' . $cat_part . '</div></div>';
            $cat_partner_parent = '<div class="category-partners"><div>' . $cat_part_parent . '</div></div>';
            $cat_partner_grandparent = '<div class="category-partners"><div>' . $cat_part_grandparent . '</div></div>';
            $cat_partner_grandgrandparent = '<div class="category-partners"><div>' . $cat_part_grandgrandparent . '</div></div>';


            if ( !empty($cat_part) ) { /* if top category has partners */
                    print_r($cat_partner);
            } elseif ( !empty($cat_part_parent) ) { /* if 1 level category has partners */
                    print_r($cat_partner_parent); 
            } elseif ( !empty($cat_part_grandparent) ) { /* if 2 level category has partners */
                    print_r($cat_partner_grandparent); 
            } elseif ( !empty($cat_part_grandgrandparent) ) { /* if 3 level category has partners */
                    print_r($cat_partner_grandgrandparent); 
            } elseif ( empty($cat_part_parent) && !empty($cat_part) ) { /* inherit from top level */
                    print_r($cat_partner); 
            } elseif ( empty($cat_part_parent) && empty($cat_part_grandparent) && !empty($cat_part) ) { /* inherit from 1 level */
                    print_r($cat_partner); 
            } elseif ( empty($cat_part_grandparent) && empty($cat_part_grandgrandparent) && !empty($cat_part_parent) ) { /* inherit from 2 level */
                    print_r($cat_partner_parent); 
            } elseif ( empty($cat_part_parent) && empty($cat_part_grandparent) && empty($cat_part_grandgrandparent) && !empty($cat_part) ) { /* inherit from 2 level */
                    print_r($cat_partner); 
            } else {
                /* Die */
            }   
        } 

    }
```

But still need to fix PHP errors $parent_one, $parent_null and $parent_two return empty.